# What are the technologies i need to know to be a Microsoft Project server developer

Tags: development, 2016, project-server, ms-project

I am a SharePoint (online & On-premsies) developer with these skills:-

1. SPFx
2. Remote event receivers & server side Event receiver
3. Power Platform; Power Apps 7 Power automate.

Now i want to work on a new project for a customer which use SharePoint on-premises 2016 with Project server. and i will be working on the Project server part, so does my skills in SharePoint Online and On-premises fit to be a Project Server developer?

Thanks